# Custom sorting function in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, sorting, object

I'm trying to write a custom sort function for my array of objects in javascript. For testing purposes, my `arr` array looks like this:

```
[{
  _id: '5798afda8830efa02be8201e',
  type: 'PCR',
  personId: '5798ae85db45cfc0130d864a',
  numberOfVotes: 1,
  __v: 0
}, {
  _id: '5798afad8830efa02be8201d',
  type: 'PRM',
  personId: '5798aedadb45cfc0130d864b',
  numberOfVotes: 7,
  __v: 0
}]
```

I want to sort the objects using this function(the criteria is `numberOfVotes`):

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.numberOfVotes > b.numberOfVotes) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (b.numberOfVotes > a.numberOfVotes) {
    return -1;
  } else return 0;
});
```

When i print the results, I receive the same order like before, aka `5798afda8830efa02be8201e,5798afad8830efa02be8201d`

Am I missing something?

Comment: Your input array is already sorted by your criteria (`numberOfVotes`). What did you expect to happen?

Comment: @melpomene i want it to be sorted descreasingly. and if i replace the "<" with ">", i receive the same result

Comment: Try `arr.sort(function (a, b) { return b.numberOfVotes - a.numberOfVotes; });`.

Comment: @Issue429 if you change both signs to < you'll get the opposite order

Comment: @alebianco i've changed them but receive the same ordering, that's the problem :(

Comment: @Issue429 So show your actual code.

Comment: @melpomene , you were right. you're solution solves the problem. i wasn't seeing the solution because i was still printing something else, not the array. thank you alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sort by descending order of votes:

```js
var arr = [{_id: '5798afda8830efa02be8201e',type: 'PCR',personId: '5798ae85db45cfc0130d864a',numberOfVotes: 1,__v: 0}, {_id: '5798afad8830efa02be8201d',type: 'PRM',personId: '5798aedadb45cfc0130d864b',numberOfVotes: 7,__v: 0}];

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b.numberOfVotes - a.numberOfVotes;
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: i've marked this answer as right because it is smarter made, even though the ideea was @melpomene 's

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to sort by descending order of votes.

You need to change the condition in if block. Also note id like `5798afda8830efa02be8201e` is wrong, It need to be string `'5798afda8830efa02be8201e'`

```js
    var arr=[{
      _id: '5798afda8830efa02be8201e',
      type: 'PCR',
      personId: '5798ae85db45cfc0130d864a',
      numberOfVotes: 1,
      __v: 0
    }, {
      _id: '5798afad8830efa02be8201d',
      type: 'PRM',
      personId: '5798aedadb45cfc0130d864b',
      numberOfVotes: 7,
      __v: 0
    }]
    
    arr.sort( function ( a, b ) {
          if ( a.numberOfVotes < b.numberOfVotes ) {
            return 1;
          }
          else if ( b.numberOfVotes < a.numberOfVotes ) {
            return -1;
          } else{return 0;}
       });
    
    console.log(arr)
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/4m7dn5ha/1/)